# laravel not showing error but only http:500 error?

Tags: laravel

i have enabled Laravel debug  true and also error in .env and storage folder permission is also 777 and also tried with 0775 but Laravel is not showing cause of 500 error in logs

Comment: Does your webserver has write permission to the `bootstrap/` folder?

Comment: Make sure you're looking both in Laravel's logs (`storage/logs`) *and* your webserver's logs. Sometimes Laravel is too broken to write to its own logs; they'll typically wind up in the webserver's logs in that case.

Comment: can you elaborate little bit

Comment: where you are getting this error

Answer (score 0):

This error come most of the time because of folder permissions. You need to give permissions 777 recursively to your folders like

```
sudo chmod 777 laravel/public -R
sudo chmod 777 laravel/storage -R
```

You can check I hope It will fix the issue, If not then you need to do some more steps in linux. Here is detail: https://rapidsol.blogspot.com/2018/12/how-to-disable-selinux-security.html?q=composer